# passing a parameter to GridView when calling data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

so my GridView Returns all the data in my Table but i want to return data that are related to the  UserName attribute in the table,mind you that i have Multiple UserName's in the table.

i tried giving my function a string username and in my page_load:

```
string SessionName;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SessionName = Session["Username"].ToString();
    DataSet ds = InsertClass.GetCart(SessionName);


}
```

in my class:

```
public static DataSet GetCart(string UserName)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString());
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [ShoppingCart] WHERE UserName = @UserName ", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", UserName));


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter1.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

Edit:my mistake guys i didnt add the parameter to my function because i was trying alot of things before i asked the question and forgot to put it back.

Comment: in a text command I usually don't do parameters but a quick search showed me that you do cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(....); instead of cmd.Parameters.Add(....); http://dan.folkes.me/2011/09/21/asp-net-adding-parameters-to-commandtype-text/

Comment: You are not passing `username` as string parameter here in your code `public static DataSet GetCart()`

Comment: ok what happen when you write it like this what do you have in the dataset, do you have any exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing `username` as string parameter here in your code `public static DataSet GetCart()`

Here is correct one:

```
public static DataSet GetCart(string userName)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString());
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [ShoppingCart] WHERE UserName = @UserName ", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter1.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: forgot to add it before the post sorry

Answer (score 0):

So in your page_load you are calling your GetCart function with parameter SessionName, but i cannot see your GetCart function is taking any parameter:

```
DataSet ds = InsertClass.GetCart(SessionName);

public static DataSet GetCart()
{.....}
```

And what is the reference of UserName, when you add the parameter to sql query:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", UserName));
```

Did you debug and see that you are passing the right parameter ?

Comment: forgot to add it before the post sorry